# Can I force an application to use a specific font?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

How can I change the default font for a specific application in Windows 7?

I'm running an application which should have a specific font as its default... but I'm getting MS Sans Serif as the default.

Can this be changed? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that all applications use the font you want, you could follow these steps:

[How to Change the Default Fonts in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1175-fonts-change.html)

if this doesn't change it, then the font is hard-coded into the application and we probably can't fix it.